# How to set database SqlCe path in wpf windowes application?

Tags: c#, wpf

My data base present in currant project folder in **"Earnest_Indieiduals"**

```
 public DataBaseConnection()
    {
        try
        {

            _connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=D:\Earnest  Indieiduals\Earnest_Indieiduals\Earnest_Indieiduals\MyDatabase#1.sdf;Password=xxxxxx;");

        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
    }
```

It will work. But its an path dependent. I want path in dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string path =Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyDatabase#1.sdf");
_connection =new SqlCeConnection(string.Format(@"Data Source={0};Password=xxxxxx;",path));
```